# Moving Windows with Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, fullscreen

I often work with fullscreen apps and I'm moving between apps with three-finger right/left on touchpad or mostly doing that with the keyboard (<kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>/ <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>).

And sometimes using <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to see which windows I have. I'm talking about this screen:

[image: Screenshot of macOS's Mission Control interface]

The problem is when I want to **move** or **arrange windows**, I need to use my mouse (or touchpad) and drag/drop the windows, which is non-efficient. I want to arrange them **with keyboar**d (for example I have 2 VSCode full-screen windows and I want to move it to left).

Is there any way to move windows with keyboard. Any solution (native or open-source) is accepted.

PS 1: I'm using macOS High Sierra.

PS 2: Don't kill me if it's already answered. Just give me the link and question will deleted.(^_^)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcut to switch between applications in Mission Control](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127240/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-applications-in-mission-control)

Comment: Nope mate. Cause my problem is not about changing current screen. The issue is about arrangement. I want to arrange them with keyboard. 
Thanks for editing by the way.

Comment: Sorry about that my reading of the other question was (and still is) as such, bit I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: Does this answer over here resolve your issue. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/how-to-arrange-two-windows-easily-to-left-and-right-side

Comment: Nope. I am not talking about arranging two windows on same screen. Seriously I can not be the only guy who using windows full-screen and swipe them easily.

Comment: There is definitely no built-in mechanism in macOS for what you want. You can get close by using a tiling window manager like [Amethyst](https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst), but it's not great for your use case. To my knowledge, there are no known apps out there that provide the exact functionality you seek. Honestly, it bugs me, too.

Comment: Thanks for all this apps. I will check them and give feedback soon. But still maybe there is an app in the abyss of open source that we don't know yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Better Touch tool](https://folivora.ai/) is definitely the way to go. When you create a new shortcut, in the actions there is a whole category called "Navigating Spaces / Desktops". Within it you can then pick an action such as 'move left a space', 'switch to desktop 3', etc. Check it out and let us know!

Comment: Yes. As [the image](https://pasteboard.co/ITOB7Ik.png) says there is few options to moving screen. Unfortunately it didn't work with my mac (maybe its cause High Sierra 2011 so).

Comment: Bummer. I'm trying to find minimum requirements but can't find it anywhere. Maybe worth reaching out to the developers

Answer (score 2):

Another cool app for this is Magnet. I have been using this app for months and I am totally satisfied. You can find it in Mac App Store.

Comment: I think I've checked already this tool. But I'm not talking about moving windows on the screen. But thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Better Touch tool](https://folivora.ai/) and you can set custom shortcuts for window snapping

Comment: Thanks. I will check and feedback soon (I hope)